# ORA-02270 - Can't find fault

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, primary-key

Having trouble with a ORA-02270 error. After going through the primary keys and foreign keys over and over, I can't find what the problem is.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTACC(
REFNO CHAR(4), 
ACCNO NUMBER(7),
CONSTRAINT CUSTACC_PK PRIMARY KEY (REFNO, ACCNO));

CREATE TABLE CUST(
CUSTNO CHAR(4),
NAME VARCHAR2(30),
ADDRESS VARCHAR2(50),
AREA VARCHAR2(10),
CONSTRAINT CUSTNO_PK    PRIMARY KEY(CUSTNO),
CONSTRAINT CUSTNO_FK    FOREIGN KEY (CUSTNO)
    REFERENCES CUSTACC(REFNO));

CREATE TABLE ACC(
ACCNO NUMBER(7),
BALANCE NUMBER(8,2),
BRANCH VARCHAR2(10),
OPENED DATE,
BONUS NUMBER(8,2),
CONSTRAINT ACCNO_PK    PRIMARY KEY (ACCNO),
CONSTRAINT ACCNO_FK    FOREIGN KEY (ACCNO)
    REFERENCES CUSTACC(ACCNO));
```

I must be blind but I've checked everything people have suggested before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary key on `CUSTACC` consists of two columns:  `REFNO` and `ACCNO`.

The foreign key reference should include both of them.  So, your tables need both columns.

I suspect, in fact, that you want the foreign key reference in the first table, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE CUST (
    CUSTNO CHAR(4),
    NAME VARCHAR2(30),
    ADDRESS VARCHAR2(50),
    AREA VARCHAR2(10),
    CONSTRAINT CUSTNO_PK    PRIMARY KEY(CUSTNO)
);

CREATE TABLE ACC (
    ACCNO NUMBER(7),
    BALANCE NUMBER(8,2),
    BRANCH VARCHAR2(10),
    OPENED DATE,
    BONUS NUMBER(8,2),
    CONSTRAINT ACCNO_PK    PRIMARY KEY (ACCNO)
);

CREATE TABLE CUSTACC (
    REFNO CHAR(4), 
    ACCNO NUMBER(7),
    CONSTRAINT CUSTACC_PK PRIMARY KEY (REFNO, ACCNO),
    CONSTRAINT CUSTNO_FK    FOREIGN KEY (REFNO)
        REFERENCES CUST(CUSTNO),
    CONSTRAINT ACCNO_FK    FOREIGN KEY (ACCNO)
        REFERENCES ACC(ACCNO)
);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/35360e) is a SQL Fiddle.